# ReactJS Facebook login using react-facebook-login package

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, authentication

I'm trying to implement Facebook login button in ReactJS using the [react-facebook-login package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login). It is very simple to do with the piece of code provided.

However, the button does not change and keep displaying "LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK" after the user has logged in and a valid token is still there. I can see in the console.log the response including the **name**, **picture**, **id**, **accessToken**, **userID**:

***ButtonFacebookLogin.js:18***

```
Object {name: "John Doe", picture: Object, id: "101560159xxxxxxx", 
accessToken: "EAAFdByROZC…5tDST3sxnhZASZBZ", userID: "101560159xxxxxxxx"…}
```

Is it supposed to change by itself or should I change the code in the ReactJS script to check if a valid login was possible?

```
import React from 'react';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

class ButtonFacebookLogin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.responseFacebook = this.responseFacebook.bind(this);
    this.user = null;
  };

  responseFacebook(response) {
    console.log(response);
    this.user = response.name;
    console.log(this.user);
  };

  componentClicked(response) {
    console.log(response);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookLogin
        appId="383760232021913"
        autoLoad={true}
        fields="name,email,picture"
        scope="public_profile,user_friends"
        onClick={this.componentClicked}
        callback={this.responseFacebook}
      />
      // just here above the button always looks the same
    )
  }
```

Sorry the question might sound silly as I am new to ReactJS :-) and I could not find a lot of documentation on this Facebook Login Button package.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try this ,got code from travis media ,recommend checking him out

```
export default class Facebook extends Component {
    state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
      userID: "",
      name: "",
      email: "",
      picture: ""
    };
  
    
    responseFacebook = response => {
       console.log(response);
  
      this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: true,
        userID: response.userID,
        name: response.name,
        email: response.clientSecret,
        picture: response.picture.data.url
      });
    };
  
    componentClicked = () => console.log("clicked");

    render() {
      let fbContent;

      if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
        fbContent = (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "400px",
              margin: "auto",
              background: "#grey",
              padding: "20px"
            }}
          >
            <img src={this.state.picture} alt={this.state.name} />
            <h2>Welcome {this.state.name}</h2>
            Email: {this.state.email}
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        fbContent = (
          <FacebookLogin
            appId="304489330816284"
            autoLoad={false}
            fields="name,email,picture"
            onClick={this.componentClicked}
            callback={this.responseFacebook}
           // scope="public_profile,user_friends,user_actions.Test"
          //  callback={this.responseFacebook}
          />
        );
      }
  
      return <div>{fbContent}</div>;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to check if it's already logged in and change the `textButton` field of the `FacebookLogin` component.